# how to detect which scene? (swift/spritekit/xcode)

Tags: xcode, swift, background, scene

I am using this code for my background in the gameviewcontroller:

```
    let yourImage = UIImage(named: welkeLevel)
    let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
    self.view?.addSubview(imageview)
```

But I have a begin (menu) scene where I do not want this background and is still showing up.

How do I detect which scene I am (Gamescene / Menuscene etc.)?

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

`SKScene` is a subclass of `SKNode`. You can use the name property to do this. Just set the name of `Gamescene` or `Menuscene` to `'game'` or `'menu'` like this:

```
scene.name = "game"
```

And check the property like so:

```
if self.name == "game"{
    //Do something.
    println("game")
} else if self.name == "menu
    //Do something else.
    println("menu")
}
```

Comment: Do I put this code in the viewcontroller or in gamescene? thank you

Comment: because it says gameviewcontroller does not have a member named "name" at this line of code: if self.name == "game"{

Comment: The first block should be in your view controller, the second in the actual game scene. If you need to use the second block in your view controller just replace self with a reference to the scene you want to check.

Comment: I want to use the second block in my viewcontroller but I do not know what you mean by replace self with a reference to the scene you want to check.  I want to check is the scene is one GameScene, but if i change self.name to GameScene.name it gives error

Answer (score 0):

```
I have worked out the same issue with a replay button. I have to identify which scene the user is in and reload the same when user clicks replay button.

1) Add a extension function  to detect current game level

extension SKScene {

    static func sceneWithClassNamed(className: String, fileNamed fileName: String) -> SKScene? {
        if let SceneClass = NSClassFromString("JumperCrab.\(className)") as? SKScene.Type,
            let scene = SceneClass(fileNamed: fileName) {
                return scene
        }
        return nil
    }

    func replayCurrentScene(currentLevelName: String,currentGameSceneIndex:Int)
    {
        GameViewController().getReplayCurrentSceneDetailsToVC(currentLevelName, currentGameSceneIndex: currentGameSceneIndex)
    }
}

2) Call the above extension method in every game scene.

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.replayCurrentScene( "Round 1", currentGameSceneIndex: 0)
}

3) Set up a similar method at the View Controller.

    func getReplayCurrentSceneDetailsToVC(currentLevelName: String,currentGameSceneIndex:Int)
    {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(currentGameSceneIndex, forKey: "LevelInt")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentLevelName, forKey: "LevelName")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }

4)  Create variables 

    //GAME LEVEL
    var gameLevelSceneNameArray = NSArray()
    var currentGameSceneAtVC:String?
    var currentGameSceneIndexAtVC:Int?

5) Make my level list array

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Game Scenes
        gameLevelSceneNameArray = ["GameScene","SecondRound","ThirdRound", "FourthRound","FifthRound","SixthRound","SeventhRound", "EighthRound","NinethRound"]
}

6) Apply on the Replay Game button .

    @IBAction func replayButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    currentGameSceneIndexAtVC =   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("LevelInt")
    currentGameSceneAtVC = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("LevelName") as? String

 self.moveToSelectedGameLevel(currentGameSceneAtVC!, gameSceneName: self.gameLevelSceneNameArray[currentGameSceneIndexAtVC!] as! String)

    }

7) Set up a game scene navigation too (using switch case )


func moveToSelectedGameLevel(levelNameString:String, gameSceneName:String)
    {
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        switch(levelNameString)
        {
        case "Round 1":
            if let gameScene = SKScene.sceneWithClassNamed(gameSceneName, fileNamed: gameSceneName) {
                skView.presentScene(gameScene)
            }
        case "Round 2" :
            if let gameScene = SKScene.sceneWithClassNamed(gameSceneName, fileNamed: gameSceneName) {
                skView.presentScene(gameScene)
            }
        case "Round 3":
            if let gameScene = SKScene.sceneWithClassNamed(gameSceneName, fileNamed: gameSceneName) {
                skView.presentScene(gameScene)
        default:
            print("")
        }
    }
```